# 301 Redirect old Wordpress URL to new one

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've just moved from Wordpress to a different CMS.

Sorry if this question has been asked before (I'm sure it has, but I browsed about 30 posts and didn't find what I need)

I need to change my htaccess file so that old urls redirect to new format.

OLD URL format:
www.mysite.com/my-post/

NEW URL format: 
www.mysite.com/my-post.html

I need exactly the opposite of this: [HTACCESS - Replace everything ending html with a trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166307/htaccess-replace-everything-ending-html-with-a-trailing-slash)

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

This should redirect anything that ends in a forward slash with `.html` so `example.com/test/` becomes `example.com/test.html`, but `example.com/test` would  be unmodified (does not end in a forward slash).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/ /$1.html [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```